# How to hide the area outside of TStyledControl rect that has inside other controls

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I have a control derived from TStyledControl that I create at runtime, inside the constructor a TImage control is getting created that is larger that the parent control. My issue is that the TImage is visible even if it is clipping outside of the parent control. What I want to do is clip the space outside of the parent control to show only the part inside of parent's rect, let's say the parent is 400x400 pixels and the child is 500x450 pixels at 0:0 position, I want to show only the part that is inside the parent's rect and clip the rest 100 pixels on the right and the 50 pixels of the bottom. Another example is like above but the child control's position is at 20:20 I want to clip the 20 pixels on the left, the 80 pixels on the right, the 20 pixels on the top and the 30 pixels on the bottom.

Is there a function or a way to do this?

Comment: have you tried to use `parent.ClipChildren`?

Comment: ClipChildren will only show you that a control is clipped (in this case the TImage control). It does not actual clip that content. For example TWinControl from the VCL does not draw outside of it's rect. I want something similar but for firemonkey.

Comment: Well, a tiny test proves @teran right. Setting `ClipChildren := True` seems to do what you want. Compare FM with VCL as much as you like, but they're simply not the same.

Comment: Alright teran is right, I was putting the ClipChildren := True to the image :/ You can put it as an answer to accept it!